# Search Query not functioning properly in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

```
public static function searchSubmissions($request, $candidateIds = array(),$isscontact = NULL){
      $querys = DB::table('submissions')->select('submissions.*');
  if ( Input::has('candidatename') and $request->input('candidatename') != NULL){
      $querys->join('candidates','candidates.candidateid','=','submissions.candidateid');
      $querys->where('candidates.firstname', 'LIKE', '%'. $request->input('candidatename').'%')->orWhere('candidates.lastname', 'LIKE', '%'. $request->input('candidatename') .'%')->where('submissions.status','1');
  }
   $result = $querys->paginate(PAGELIMIT);

  return $result ;
}
```

> This is my search query if I entered "john" or "peter" in my search field it works fine. if I entered full name "john peter" it does not work for me.
>   **In my database I have two fields 'firstname' 'lastname'**

Comment: simply because there's no `john peter`.

Comment: You should learn how `LIKE` clause works in MySQL (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/pattern-matching.html)

Comment: Is there any chance?? because i have john in my firstname. In my query also I used 'LIKE', '%'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think, you need to refactor your code to work it properly.

```
$names = explode(' ', $request->input('candidatename'));

if (!empty($names)) {
    foreach ($names as $name) {
        $querys = $querys->orWhere('candidates.firstname', 'LIKE', '%'. $name .'%');
        $querys = $querys->orWhere('candidates.lastname', 'LIKE', '%'. $name .'%');
    }
}
```

Have a look at this https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries#parameter-grouping

Comment: Thanks a lot mate. Now its functioning correctly. Today you teach me a great lesson

Comment: You should also know from shyammakwana.me comments.

Comment: Yeah sure bro _/\_